# Rust Single threaded Persistent TCP Server

Tags: multithreading, rust, tcp, connection, threadpool

I'm trying to make a server in Rust using tcp protocol. I can make a normal server, through the language documentation, but I don't want that whenever a new connection is made, a new thread is created, nor do I want to use a thread pool, because the tcp connections will be persistent, that is, they will last a long time (around 30min-2h). So, I looped over all the connections and, with a 1 millisecond timeout, I try to read if there are any new packets. However, something tells me this is not the right thing to do. Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think it depends on the operating system. Linux gives you abstraction to "loop over" all open sockets, which is called polling. Basically you provide a list of sockets and OS returns a list of ones with data available. Also there are a lot of libraries to do asynchronious IO on crates. They should do the right thing for you.

Comment: "*However, something tells me this is not the right thing to do.*" What is that something?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for some asynchronous runtime. Like most runtimes, `tokio` can be customized to work with a single thread, if you don't have many connections you centainly don't need more than one. If we translate the example @Benjamin Boortz provided:

```rust
use tokio::io::*;
use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};

#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").await.unwrap();
    while let Ok((stream, _address)) = listener.accept().await {
        // this is similar to spawning a new thread.
        tokio::spawn(handle_connection(stream));
    }
}

async fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
    stream.read(&mut buffer).await.unwrap();
    println!("Request: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]));
}
```

This code is concurrent, yet single threaded, which seems to be what you want. I recommend you check the [tokio tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial). It is a really good resource if you are unfamiliar with asynchronous programming in Rust.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you need but you can find in "The Rust Programming Language" Book an example for a single threaded TCP Server. https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-01-single-threaded.html

Please refer to Listing 20-2:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        handle_connection(stream);
    }
}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];

    stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();

    println!("Request: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]));
}
```

Ref: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-01-single-threaded.html#reading-the-request

Comment: That code will wait for each connection to finish before it can receive the next one. No, that's not what I'm looking for, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @MiguelCarvalho can you please express what exactly you want to achieve and why you want to avoid threads and thread pools? For me it sounds that you need a multi-threaded TCP server without any threadng? Have you already tried tokio? like https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/examples/echo.rs . Sure, it uses threading.

Comment: I want to avoid threads because the connections are persistent (imagine I establish 30 connections: that would be 30 threads, which is very resource-consuming). A thread pool would not be good either as it would only have X maximum possible connections at a time. My goal is, instead of having a thread dedicated to each connection, to have a single thread that loops through all the connections and checks if new packets have been sent.

Comment: @MiguelCarvalho 30 threads is not a lot by the standards of most common operating systems. I'd probably recommend the simple thing first (spawning a thread for each connection), and then doing something more complicated if you're sure to need it. The alternative is an asynchronous implementation, which may process multiple connections on the same thread concurrently. `tokio` is indeed the most common async runtime, but there are others too.

Comment: Quote: "A thread pool would not be good either as it would only have X maximum possible connections at a time." @MiguelCarvalho: How come you see this restriction?

Comment: @MekeorMelire A thread pool is a list of threads (like 4 or 5) where each thread handles something specific (a connection in this case). When a connection is closed, that thread is available to receive another connection. This means that, at most, the thread pool can only handle 4 or 5 connections at a time. I am looking for something bigger. But I've already found the solution: tokio tasks.

Comment: @MiguelCarvalho: At the end of the day, are tokio-tasks effectively different from looping over the connections with a timeout?